# How do I replace tokens in Nuspec file when packaging a Nuget package?

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build the [`Xamarin.Forms`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) nuget package. This is a `PCL` library.

I have the following command:

```
..\..\..\Nuget\Nuget.exe pack ..\.\.nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.nuspec -build
```

But I get the error:

> The replacement token 'IdAppend' has no value

How do I replace the tokens in the Nuspec file when packaging?

Comment: Just manually edit the <id> section?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Is it not possible to feed these in at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just manually substituting in the values using *Find and Replace* in Word.

Seemed the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -Properties argument for this

```
nuget.exe pack ... -Properties idAppend=whaterver;SomeOtherProperty=bla,bla,bla
```